# JQuery Mousemove div class e.pageX positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using this code:

```
$('.my_img').mousemove(function(e){
   $('.mycls').css("left",e.pageX-20+"px");
   $('.mycls').css("top",e.pageY-10+"px");

});
```

then...

```
<div class="mycls">I Move</div>
```

then...

```
<img class="my_img" src="myimg.png" />
```

My problem is that if I add any div's above these divs the position changes and mycls is no longer at mouse position.

So if I was to add to extra div's after the body like this:

```
<div>ONE</div>

<div>TWO</div>
```

...then the rest of the code...I will lose the position :o/

Any ideas on how to sort this?

Comment: Since you have CSS issues, it would be nice to see the CSS code, or even a demo.

Comment: There's no css right now ...just the top and left positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *e.pageX* and *e.pageY* values are relative to the entire page, your code shouldn't be affected by adding new elements. If you set *top* and *left* to an element, it defines its distance from the top and left of the page.

The only case where it could be problematic is if you have *position:relative* set on any parent elements of the *mycls* div. Remove that *position:relative*, so that *top* and *left* refer to the entire page and not the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

simply add a CSS `position:absolute;` to your movable element `.mycls`

Comment: That is still out of position. An alternative to e.pageX where it's relative to the Div and not the page would work wonders :o/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var img = document.getElementById("my_img");
var cls = document.getElementById("mycls");
img.onmousemove = function(e){
   cls.style.left = e.clientX-20 + "px";
   cls.style.top =  e.clientY-10 + "px";
};
```

```css
#mycls {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
#my_img {
  width: 420px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333;    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_img">
  <div id="mycls">
  Your message here
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example of how I have done this in the past ... importantly
the div that is moving is a child of the container so that a any mousemove events it triggers are bubbled to the parent for handling